# Microsoft Graph API - OData Filter - Invalid filter clause

Tags: odata, azure-ad-graph-api

I cannot seem to get an Odata filter to work for the below URL... an error is always returned `Invalid filter clause`

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows/B2C_1_api-v3-signin/userflowIdentityProviders?$filter=value/domainHint eq 'mydomain.com'`

I have tried other similar combinations such as...

- $filter=domainHint eq 'mydomain.com'
- $filter=startsWith(value/domainHint, 'mydomain.com')
- $filter=startsWith(domainHint, 'mydomain.com')

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.identityProviderBase)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.openIdConnectIdentityProvider",
            "id": "OIDC-V1-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "displayName": "Azure AD",
            "clientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "clientSecret": "******",
            "scope": "openid profile",
            "metadataUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            "domainHint": "mydomain.com",
            "responseType": "code",
            "responseMode": "form_post",
            "claimsMapping": {
                "userId": "oid",
                "displayName": "name",
                "givenName": "given_name",
                "surname": "family_name",
                "email": "email"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.openIdConnectIdentityProvider",
            "id": "OIDC-V1-11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
            "displayName": "Okta",
            "clientId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
            "clientSecret": "******",
            "scope": "openid profile email",
            "metadataUrl": "https://XYZ.okta.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            "domainHint": "otherdomain.com",
            "responseType": "code",
            "responseMode": "form_post",
            "claimsMapping": {
                "userId": "sub",
                "displayName": "name",
                "givenName": "given_name",
                "surname": "family_name",
                "email": "email"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just a quick FYI: The identityProvider API is deprecated and will stop returning data on March 2023. Please use the new identityProviderBase API... So we want to use a different route for this altogether

Comment: actually this is the new API (look at the @odata.context value returned in my JSON payload)... also the documentation does not indicate this route is to be deprecated (but similar routes are)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/b2xidentityuserflow-list-userflowidentityproviders?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: My mistake I was reading that from the $metadata. They may not have enabled filtering, but have you tried to use the _PascalCase_ name: `$filter=DomainHint eq 'mydomain.com'`

Comment: it looks like filtering is not enabled for that field... the same syntax works for other fields like 'Id'... the error message could have been clearer

Answer (score -1):

You don't filter on the `value` node at all, `value` is not part of the model, it is a part of the response wrapper only.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows/B2C_1_api-v3-signin/userflowIdentityProviders?$filter=domainHint eq 'mydomain.com'
```

Comment: as indicated I have already tried that... along with a few other permutations